# Gatsby typescript css modules and vitest

Tags: typescript, gatsby, css-modules, vitest

Gatsby 5 requires you to import css modules as an exported member or a * as

```
import * as styles from ‘./index.module.css’
```

This all works fine on the Frontend and displays as expected, however when trying to run this component through a test suite. I’m using vitest it doesn’t recognise styles

If I do it the old way

```
import styles from ‘./index.module.css
```

The test suite recognises the styles but Gatsby doesn’t render the page because it thinks styles is undefined.